# JAVA Aspect Oriented Programming- Runtime Aspect Weaving and Class Loading time aspect weaving

Tags: java, aop, spring-aop

I came cross a article about AOP, there it is mentioned that Aspect weaving can happen during the compile time, class loading time and during runtime.

In java, I could imagine, rather understand, how aspect weaving would actually happens during compile time. Proxy class are generated during class compilation itself(with aspect enabled on project). Generated bytecode would have proxy code.

But I am still wondering what exactly (actually) happen, during class loading time weaving and runtime weaving. Does the proxy class gets generated while loading the class? Does aspect library add any programmatic instruction in .class (while compiling) file for proxy class generation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Spring AOP* actually uses Java Dynamic Proxies for interfaces and, if necessary, *cglib* for non-interface types. It only works for Spring Beans. Proxies are generated automatically for all methods matched by a so-called pointcut. This is done during wiring.

*AspectJ* however does not need or even use proxies, it directly generates byte code which is woven into the existing byte code. AspectJ is much more powerful and can do more than just method interception.

- For compile-time weaving (CTW) this is done by the AspectJ compiler *ajc*. Instead of native AspectJ syntax (which is a superset of Java) you can also use a Java annotation style way of defining aspects, often called the @AspectJ syntax. In this case you can compile the aspects with *javac* and use the aspect weaver in a separate build step. The result is basically the same. In both cases, during runtime you need a small AspectJ runtime library in order for the aspects to work as expected.
- The difference between CTW and LTW (load-time weaving) is that the weaving step is deferred until classloading time. In order to make this work you need a Java agent library, called the AspectJ weaver, on the JVM command line. Java agents are started before normal application classes are loaded and can thus influence classloading and instrument the loaded byte code as desired. This approach is also used by profiling tools or similar.
- So obviously LTW does not work with source code but class files, i.e. AspectJ can weave its aspect code into any regular Java class file. This can also be done before runtime, i.e. you can weave aspect code into an external library for which you do not have the source code, creating a new, modified version of it in order to save the time for LTW every time the library is loaded. This often is called binary weaving. With some extra knowledge it is even possible to weave aspect code into the JDK, i.e. by creating a modified *rt.jar* including aspect code. But this is nothing you normally do, I just wanted to mention that it is possible.

Answer (score 2):

Not necessarily at compile time. In Java, through reflection and classloader, you can see and even or modify create methods and classes at runtime, programmatically.

For example,
`"hello".getClass().getMethod("substring", Integer.TYPE).invoke("my sharona", 3)`
Will return "sharona", extracting the method substring from a String instance and applying it to another object.

Using a custom [classloader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html), you can define how your class is loaded from the system. This way you can define a method which will called to load (or generate!) the bytecode for a class. You can also use the system classloader to load the bytecode of a class and inspect it.

This technique is widely used by Mozilla Rhino, which can use it to load a compiled JavaScript as a Java bytecode for greater efficiency, or [JavAssist](http://www.csg.ci.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/), which allows you to create classes, methods, fields and anything at runtime.

Also application servers like JBoss or TomCat use reflection to inspect and manipulate the code, especially through annotations.

Comment: Got a fair idea for Class Load time weaving. But how about runtime? I am not sure what I am missing here... I have aspect related configuration in some xml file(not through annotations). After class is loaded, objects would have been created and linkage(dependency) of object would have been done. now how you fit the proxy class in between the class. For example, one servlet invokes a service. now logger is an aspect which is advised through xml file. Now how does JVM will be made aware of these at runtime?

Comment: Both reflection and class loading through a classloader work at runtime, in that case by appending the necessary bytecode to methods when a service is added. Is the server, or the library code, which uses reflection to find methods to manipulate and to change them at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what run-time weaving is. In load-time weaving the agent intercepts the class loading and modifies the byte-code before passing it on to the class loader.

To see how this works is quite easy, for example using [AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/). You could use compile time weaving and disassemble the code to see exactly how it works. AspectJ can also be instructed to save on disk the generated classes during load time weaving.

Comment: Aren't the run-time and load time weaving same??